# compile error: expected identifier or '(' numeric constant using sigaction() system call

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, signals

So far I am trying to compile [Wolfenstein: Enemy Territory](https://github.com/id-Software/Enemy-Territory) to be x86_64 native. After dealing with ASM instructions, amd64 specific processor registers and other strange stuff, I eventually got three beautiful GCC compile error:

```
url.c:xxxx:xx error: expected identifier or '(' before numeric constant
sigaction( SIGALRM, &sigact, NULL );
           ^
```

If I type "sigaction" onto Google, almost every single link is visited by me, so any help would be greeeeaaatly appreciated.

```
#include <signal.h>
```

is present.

```
#define _POSIX_SOURCE
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE
```

are present, too. By using string earch method, I can see no "overwrite" of the structure / function sigaction(), so I guess this is not the problem. Because the source file is ~ 4 000 lines long, I won't paste the whole code here (but the original is available [there](https://github.com/id-Software/Enemy-Territory/blob/master/src/curl-7.12.2/lib/url.c)). I' compiling with the following flags (orinigal Makefile(s) only had the -m32 flag which, of course, I removed):

```
gcc --std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE
```

I still get this same error. This begins to get beyond my understanding, so this is why I'm asking you: how to I get rid of this error?
From what I've read, I think it is related with POSIX not being compatible with ANSI (which won't allow to compile sigaction() ).

Also, I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 64 bits (because it came preinstalled and I've been too lazy to install anoher distro), Enemy Territory compiles with scons (my version is 2.3.0) and GCC version is 4.8.2-19 .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to include `<signal.h>`, not sure where you're getting <signals.h>.   Have a look at the man page for sigaction (`man sigaction`), you'll see the include file you need near the top of the page.

Comment: I didn't know sigaction had a manual page, but signal.h was already present (I just made a little mistake typing my question). As the man page says, the feature test macros are defined before any include. I still get the error.

Comment: How about gcc -E?  If something is getting preprocessed, that should show it.

Comment: I can't even find any reference to "url.c" (the file which gives me error) in the output I get from compiling with the -E flag.